# Parse route to get gateway / DNS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dns, routes

I would like to retrieve the DNS / gateway of the wwan0 interface into a variable. Is there an other way (more robust) than store the result of the route command within a tab an get the value by using this ID ?

```
root@sn :~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         176.28.206.105  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
176.24.196.164  *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 wwan0
176.26.210.210  176.28.211.211  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
176.28.4.4      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
172.24.201.100  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what you mean by "retrieve DNS/gateway". But if you intent to get the first two columns of the output of `route` for the wwan0 Interface, then this could be helpful:

```
dest=$(route | awk '{if($8=="wwan0") print $1}')
gw=$(route | awk '{if($8=="wwan0") print $2}')
echo "data for wwan0: $dest / $gw"
```

prints

```
data for wwan0: 176.24.196.164 / *
```

in the case of your routing table.